# How to join two arrays in a LINQ query and use the result further in the query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

Sorry for the noobish question, i have no idea about linq and have to extend a query in a code which is not from me.

Is it possible to join two enumerables which are results of two different method calls into one enumerable?

```
var attibutes = from MemberDescriptor a in
     (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this) **and** TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this))
      let attribute = a.Attributes[typeof(MyAttributeAttribute)] 
                                as MyAttributeAttribute
      where attribute != null
       select new AttributeTuple { Property = a, Attribute = attribute };
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) to concatenate two `IEnumerable<T>` sequences, however, in your case, the two objects are of different types, so this will not work properly without also using [`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).

You could potentially treat both as [MemberDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.memberdescriptor.aspx) via:

```
var search = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this).Cast<MemberDescriptor>()
               .Concat(TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this).Cast<MemberDescriptor>());

var attibutes = from MemberDescriptor a in search
            let attribute = a.Attributes[typeof(MyAttributeAttribute)] as MyAttributeAttribute
            where attribute != null
            select new AttributeTuple { Property = a, Attribute = attribute };
```